# Oracle SQL: Select Distinct combination of two columns among other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

I am an Oracle SQL beginner and hope someone here can help me with this.

I have a pretty basic Select query which works so far. 
This is selecting click data, i.e. how often a user clicks on a certain class of buttons on a website.

My problem is that **I need to exclude duplicate or multiple clicks from the same user but only those that are duplicates**.

Each user has a unique ID (`CUSTOMER_ID`) and I can get either the HIT_DAY or the `HIT_DATETIME` to identify the time of the click. 
However, there are scenarios where a user needs to click multiple buttons of the same class the same day.

Is there something along the lines of "get me **only records where** the user (`CUSTOMER_ID`) is different OR where **the click time (`HIT_DATETIME`) is unique for +/- 10 seconds** ? Or anything else I could do here ? 
I don't have other unique identifiers.

**My query:**

```
SELECT
    owh.HIT_DAY
    , owh.HIT_DATETIME
    , COUNT(owh.CUSTOMER_ID) AS COUNT_CUSTOMER_ID
    , owh.IS_P_CUSTOMER AS P_CUSTOMER
    , owh.SHORTENED_URL AS URL_SHORTENED
    , owh.MP
FROM
    O_WIN_HITS owh
WHERE 1=1
    AND ...
    AND ...
    AND ...
    AND ...
GROUP BY
    owh.HIT_DAY
    , owh.HIT_DATETIME
    , owh.IS_P_CUSTOMER
    , owh.SHORTENED_URL
    , owh.MP
ORDER BY
    owh.HIT_DAY DESC
```

**Note:** This is part of a larger query.

Many thanks in advance for any help, 
Mike

Comment: it is unclear from the explanation. can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: So when a user clicks once, then 9 secs later, then 9 secs later, then 9 secs later, I count the four as one click. When a user clicks once, then 9 secs later, then 11 secs later, then 9 secs later, I count the four as two clicks. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select owh.*
from (select owh.*,
             lag(hit_datetime) over (partition by customer_id order by hit_datetime) as prev_hdt
      from O_WIN_HITS owh
     ) owh
where prev_hdt is null or
      hit_datetime > prev_hdt + 10 / (24 * 60 * 60);
```

This returns rows that are either the first row for the customer or appear for a customer more than 10 seconds after the previous hit.

Comment: Thanks so much, Gordon - this is exactly what I was looking for here. Huge help ! :)